# Let $f$ be continuous on $M=A\cup B$, then $f$ is continuous on every $x\in A\cap B$.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $M=A\cup B$, a metric space. If $f:M\to N$ is such that $f|A$ and $f|B$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous in each point $x\in A\cap B$.

My approach: If $f:M\to N$, is such that $f|A$ is continuous, then given $\epsilon>0$, is possible find $\delta_A>0$ such that for all $x\in A$, $d(a,x)<\delta_A$ implies $d(f(x),f(a))<\epsilon$. Analogous with $f|B$, for $x\in B$, $d(b,x)<\delta_B$ implies $d(f(b),f(x))<\epsilon$. Is clear that, $x\in A\cup B$,  and now take $\delta=min\{\delta_A,\delta_B\}$... but I do not know how put together both results. Or maybe work, define a new metric...hint please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any topological spaces $M,N$, a function $f:M \to N$ is continuous if and only the following holds at each $x \in M $: For every neighborhood $ V $of $f(x)$ in $ N$,  there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. So for $ x \in A \cap B$ ,and a nbhd $V$ of $f(x)$ in $N$, there are nbhds $U_A$ and $U_B$ of $x$ in the space $M$ such that $f(A \cap U_A) \subset V$ and $f(B \cap U_B) \subset V$. Now $ C=(U_A \cap U_B) \cap (A \cap B)$ is a nbhd of $x$ in $ A \cap B $ and $f (C) \subset V$.

Answer (score 3):

For your approach, I would suggest assuming $x \in A\cap B$ and then use the Max of the $\delta _x$'s.

Another approach : consider $V$ open in $N$. Then $f^{-1}(V)= (f^{-1}(V)\cap A) \cup (f^{-1}(V) \cap B)=f^{-1}(V)|_A \cup f^{-1}(V)|_{B}$ , then use continuity of the restrictions together with properties of open sets under union.